# Windows 10 apps missing with roaming profiles

Tags: windows-10, roaming-profile

We use roaming profiles in our environment and am having an issue with Windows 10 deployments and I have narrowed it down to an issue with the fact that its a roaming profile because it does not happen in local profiles so thats why Im posting this in serverfault and not super user.

When a user logs in for the first time on a newly imaged windows 10 PC, they only have 5 windows 10 apps and those are cortana, settings, and a few built in others.  Doing a search with the full name of the app will find more like Word and Excel.

When the user logs off the computer and back on, a majority of the apps show up properly and it looks fairly normal except certain apps like calculator and sticky notes are missing entirely.  When trying to search for them, you are prompting for stuff on the Microsoft store but we are locked down by STIGs so the store is disabled.

Upon further checking, when the local profile is deleted off the computer and the user logs into it again, everything is completely normal.  Calculator, Sticky Notes, Office, everything is as it should be and life can go on.  Only 25% of my environment is Windows 10 so we have some work to do but does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

I have tried installing the app manually, checking folder redirection for AppData\Local and LocalRow, and a variety of other commands that seem more focused on the issue being related to 1709 but we are on 1803.

Update: So just for $hits and giggles, I copied the AppData\Local folder from my local Windows 10 machine to the one I am testing with and am missing the calculator and sticky notes on and after a reboot, everything comes up properly!  I feel like the AppData\Local is not building itself all the way.  Its like it stops at a certain point.

Update: after working on this all day yesterday, I discovered the issue is with the settings.cache file in AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\DeviceSearchCache.  When I replace this file with another from a working computer, it works perfectly and all my apps come back.  Put the original back in and the apps are missing again.

Comment: For your consideration: https://tweaks.com/windows/67273/just-say-no-to-roaming-profiles/

Comment: Yea we are considering it.  I actually discovered a lot about this yesterday that I just updated in the OP